# Is there any tiny cms available for php

Tags: php, mysql, content-management-system

I am using joomla , oscommerce and php cms. Sometimes it becomes difficult for me to make pages by using those cms . what i usually do is

```
1)Create my own php file  like privacy.php
2)make separate table in mysql
3)Put the html content in mysql table field
4)Get that column using php

Backend

1)Make the new page in which user can edit that content using WSIWYG EDITOR
```

Is there any ready made small php script for that which can do that stuff automatically , i mean , create the databse field and front pages automatically  and i can just copy and paste that in any php supported site and it should be independent of cms.

I can code my own like that , if something like that is already there. it can save my time . ijust need to create simple pages like privacy , disclaimer , aboutus etc

Comment: It's pretty easy to build your own with something like cakePHP

Comment: can i build in simple php without framework

Comment: yup. I mentioned cakephp because it has some hefty code generation tools

Answer (score -1):

... I was searching for the best/tiny php cms and i came to the conclusion that wordpress does the trick.
It's not just a blogging platform,it is a very good cms

- there already are a lot of plugins that may come in handy
- it already comes with tinyMce as a rich-text editor (and works great)